# JPA Date comparison not working

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I have an Entity that has a `NameQuery` like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ping")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Ping.getPingsOlderThan", query = "SELECT p FROM Ping p WHERE p.pingTime > :time")
})
public class Ping extends BaseModel implements Serializable{
...

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "ping_time")
private Date pingTime;
```

And I call that `NamedQuery` form this code:

```
 public List<Ping> getPingsOlderThan(Integer seconds) {
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        //make sure seconds is negative, so it subtracts
        seconds = seconds > 0 ? seconds * -1 : seconds;
        now.add(Calendar.SECOND, seconds);
        Date time = now.getTime();
        try{
            Query query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Ping.getPingsOlderThan");
            query.setParameter("time", time);
            return query.getResultList();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not get pings",e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Basically it gets all `Pings` that are older than the the seconds pass in (at least thats what it is supposed to do). So if 30 is passed in, it should get all `Pings` in the last 30 seconds. What I get are all `Pings` in the database. Even those older than than the value I pass in.

Is there something wrong with my query? Does it have anything to do with the fact that I use a `java.util.Date`?

Comment: When I had an issue comparing dates, it turned out the date was being truncated when inserted into the database, the time of date was always set as midnight. Maybe something similar is happening here?

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with java.util.Date. I would just make a java.sql.Date. Just do `query.setParameter( "time", new java.sql.Date( time.getTime() ) );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to pass in the `TemporalType` to the query paramater. Otherwise, it was using the `Date` version which didnt have seconds.

```
query.setParameter("time", time,TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);
```